# How to properly format sum code?

Tags: java, sum

```
double SP = 0;
double SP = 0;
double sum = 0;
String name = "done";
System.out.print("Enter Stock Price of Last 5 days, then enter 'done' when finished: ");
while (name.equals("done")) {
    sum =+ SP;
    SP = input.nextDouble();
}
System.out.println(sum);
```

I'm trying to get this chunk of code to find the sum of user-inputted numbers, but I can't seem to figure out how to display the sum. Can anyone see what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try in following way,

```
String stock = "";
double sum = 0.0;
System.out.println("Enter Stock Price of Last 5 days, then enter 'done' when finished: ");

while(!(stock = input.nextLine()).equalsIgnoreCase("done")) {
    double stockValue = Double.parseDouble(stock );
    sum += stockValue;
}
```

Note that it shoule be `+=` to add in `sum` instead of `=+`. 
Currently, you code is in infinite loop because `name.equals("done")` will be always `true`. Moreover, `nextDouble` can not read `String` `done` and so you should use `nextLine`. Cherry on the top, better to use [`equalsIgnoreCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) to match user's input irrespective of case.

Comment: Up vote for you are the only one pointing out `=+` being wrong

Comment: Is String stock supposed to be empty? There was an error message saying that complained about the empty string.

Answer (score 3):

Problem is with your code here which would go in an infinite loop since you never reset `name` variable:

```
 while (name.equals("done")) {
    sum =+ SP;
    SP = input.nextDouble();
    }
```

One way to solve is, You could ask for string input and then decide whether you want to proceed or not like:

```
while(true) {
    name = input.nextLine();
    if ("done".equals(name)) {
       break;
    }
    SP = Double.valueOf(name);
    sum += SP;
 }
```

Comment: This will throw `NumberFormatException` when `done` will be provided as input.  NumberFormatException is thrown -- if the string does not contain a parsable number. Submitted a edit to solve this though.

Answer (score 0):

As the value of name is never changing and is always `done` the loop will never terminate. Change the code to something similar to below:

```
        double sum = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter Stock Price of Last 5 days, then enter 'done' when finished: ");
        // As suggested in comments if input is a scanner 
        // then it does not have method nextString instead 
        // it should be just next
        String name = input.nextString();
        while (!name.equals("done")) {
            sum =+ Integer.parseInt(name);
            name = input.nextString();
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
```

Comment: if  `input` is a scanner then it does not have method `nextString` instead it should be just `next`.

Answer (score 0):

Add `stop condition` for your `infinitive` `while loop`.